# List Iterator Not incrementable - Runtime Error

Tags: c++, list, stl, stringstream

I am getting a List Iterator Not incrementable on the code below after adding a stringstream for movieName and am unsure as how to go about solving the error. I am trying to read in from a file and add the items into a list then itterate through the list and add eash word from the title of the movie into another list.  Any help would be appreciated!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <list>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
list <string> movieList;
list <string>::iterator iterMovie; 

list <string> *titleWordList = new list <string>;
list <string>::iterator iterTitleWord; 

ifstream inFile;
inFile.open("JamesBond.txt"); 

if (!inFile)
{
    cout << "Could not find the specified file.";
}
else 
{
    movieList.clear();
    string movieName;

    while(getline(inFile,movieName))
    {
        movieList.push_back((movieName));

        /*
        for each(string movieName in movieList)
        {
            titleWordList->push_back(movieName); 
        }
        */

        stringstream ss(movieName);
        while (ss >> movieName)
        {
             titleWordList->push_back(movieName); 
        }

    }
}

if (movieList.empty())
{
    cout << "No Data Found!" << endl; 
}
else
{
    cout << "Writing Output: \n\n";

    for (iterMovie=movieList.begin(); iterMovie !=movieList.end(); ++iterMovie)
    {
        cout << *iterMovie << endl; 

    }

    for (iterTitleWord=movieList.begin(); iterTitleWord != movieList.end();     ++iterMovie)
    {
        cout << *iterTitleWord << endl;
        cout << &titleWordList; 
    }


  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the second `for` there is a copy paste error, it should be `++iterTitleWord` instead of `++iterMovie`.

Also, as @Greg suggested, `iterTitleWord=movieList.begin()` and `iterTitleWord != movieList.end()` should be `iterTitleWord=titleWordList->begin()` and `iterTitleWord != titleWordList->end()` respectively.

Comment: It looks like he meant to use titleWordList.begin and end as well.

Comment: If I follow the above answer I get the following errors:

IntelliSense: expression must have class type  63
IntelliSense: expression must have class type  63

Comment: @user1411112: Are you getting any *compiler* errors other than from intellisense?

Comment: It should be fine in that case.. I wouldn't worry too much about the intellisesne errors.

Comment: The program will not compile without fixing the intellisense error.